# BigQuery Time String like in Google Analytics H*HH:MM:SS

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Anybody was wondering how to get these weird time strings in BigQuery look like the ones in Google Analytics?

They consist of `[any amount of hours]:[minutes]:[seconds]` that's why normal time functions don't really work.

Examples:

- 85667:34:02
- 260:59:34
- 02:01:01

Answer (score 4):

> Would be cool if anyone finds a solution with fewer functions involved and posts it here

The only what makes me (always) a little dizzy is use of those `CAST`s, `FLOOR`s and `MOD`s

So, below is a little more aesthetic (from my prospective) version of that transforming to ga format

Simple example first - i think it is self-explanatory

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `table` AS (
  SELECT 1925 AS seconds  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3600             UNION ALL
  SELECT 86430            UNION ALL
  SELECT 1111111925 
)
SELECT seconds, 
  FORMAT('%02d:%s', hours, FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%M:%S', ts)) as ga_style
FROM `table`, 
UNNEST([STRUCT(
  TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(seconds) AS ts, 
  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(seconds), TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(0), HOUR) AS hours
)])
```

with result as

```sql
Row       seconds       ga_style     
1           1,925       00:32:05     
2           3,600       01:00:00     
3          86,430       24:00:30     
4   1,111,111,925   308642:12:05
```

Finally, below is above logic wrapped with SQL UDF and applied to the same script as in OP's answer

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION time_str(seconds INT64) AS ((
  SELECT FORMAT('%02d:%s', hours, FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%M:%S', ts)) 
  FROM UNNEST([STRUCT(
    TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(seconds) AS ts, 
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(seconds), TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(0), HOUR) AS hours
  )]) 
));
SELECT
  device.browser, 
  time_str(SUM(totals.timeOnSite)) timeOnSite
FROM `google.com:analytics-bigquery.LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910`
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY SUM(totals.timeOnSite) DESC
```

or to simplify even more:

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION time_str(seconds INT64) AS (
  FORMAT('%02d:%s', 
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(seconds), TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(0), HOUR), 
    FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%M:%S', TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(seconds))
  ) 
);
SELECT
  device.browser, 
  time_str(SUM(totals.timeOnSite)) timeOnSite
FROM `google.com:analytics-bigquery.LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910`
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY SUM(totals.timeOnSite) DESC
```

with result as

```sql
Row browser          timeOnSite  
1   Chrome             00:32:05  
2   Firefox            00:12:40  
3   Android Browser    00:05:04  
4   Safari             00:03:28  
5   Internet Explorer  00:00:26
```

Note: even though my focus was mostly on aesthetic aspect - meantime this version has 6 functions vs. 8 in original post - if it really matter :o)

Comment: I like this solution! I never thought of using a time diff function ... very cool. However, when you mentioned the `CAST`s and `FLOOR`s I wanted to explain - and it made me think: Yeah, I'm using it because the numbers become float - but wait, isn't there an integer division? And yes, there is :D So I will optimize my query. But I think your approach might be more readable

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a temporary function (which expects seconds) to concatenate 3 values:

- hours: cut off minutes and seconds by division /3600 and
- minutes: cut off second with division and floor; cut off hours with modulo
- seconds: cut off minutes and hours with modulo

All resulting integers are formatted to show two zeros.

### Example code:

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION time_str(seconds INT64) AS (
  FORMAT("%02d:%02d:%02d",
    DIV(seconds,3600),
    MOD(DIV(seconds,60) , 60),
    MOD(seconds, 60) 
  )
);

SELECT
  device.browser, 
  time_str(SUM(totals.timeOnSite)) timeOnSite
FROM
  `google.com:analytics-bigquery.LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910`
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY SUM(totals.timeOnSite) DESC
```

Hope that helps!

Would be cool if anyone finds a solution with fewer functions involved and posts it here.

Thanks [Elliott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6253347/elliott-brossard) and [Mikhail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221944/mikhail-berlyant) for the hints!

Comment: One small optimization: you can use a single call to `FORMAT` with multiple arguments, right? `FORMAT("%02d:%02d:%02d", ...)`